# external LDAP connection using JpsContextFactory

Tags: java, oracle, ldap, weblogic, oracle-adf

I am trying to connect to an external weblogic embeded LDAP in Oracle ADF.
I've just found a good sample code that uses JpsContextFactory class, it doesnt get any url, username and password. it seems that it connects to local weblogic ldap by defult. I could not figure out how to set a connection to an external weblogic ldap using this class.

the sample code :

```
private void initIdStoreFactory() {
    JpsContextFactory ctxFactory;
    try {
        ctxFactory = JpsContextFactory.getContextFactory();
        JpsContext ctx = ctxFactory.getContext();
        LdapIdentityStore idStoreService = (LdapIdentityStore) ctx.getServiceInstance(IdentityStoreService.class);

        ldapFactory = idStoreService.getIdmFactory();

        storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_USER_SEARCH_BASES, USER_BASES);
        storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_GROUP_SEARCH_BASES, GROUP_BASES);
        storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_USER_CREATE_BASES, USER_BASES);
        storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_GROUP_CREATE_BASES, GROUP_BASES);
        storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_GROUP_SELECTED_CREATE_BASE, GROUP_BASES[0]);
        storeEnv.put(OIDIdentityStoreFactory.RT_USER_SELECTED_CREATE_BASE, USER_BASES[0]);
    } catch (JpsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Jps Exception encountered", e);
    }
}
```

any suggestion how to use this code to connect to external ldap will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JpsContextFactory is utilised to retrieve the current information of the identity store(s) inside weblogic. In order to use it with an external LDAP, you need first to add a new security provider in Weblogic and declare it as required in order for your application to utilise the new external ldap.

Check this old article of how to do it (http://www.itbuzzpress.com/weblogic-tutorials/securing-oracle-weblogic/configuring-oracle-weblogic-security-providers.html)